# TF: Allocator out of memory on 16GB card

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to train a keras model with roughly 8 million trainable parameters on the caravan dataset from [this](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/carvana-image-masking-challenge/data) kaggle competition. The dataset has around 5000 images.
The original images have 1918x1280 pixel and are scaled down to 512x512 for training.

I'm loading the data with the Dataset API.

```py
def randomize_image(image, seed: int, apply_color_changes: bool):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image, seed=seed)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image, seed=seed)
    image = tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor = 0.2,seed=seed)(image)
    if apply_color_changes:
        image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=.4, upper=.6,seed=seed)
        image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=.2,seed=seed)
        image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, lower=.4, upper=.6,seed=seed)
        image = tf.image.random_hue(image, max_delta=.2,seed=seed)
    return image

def randomize_images(image, mask):
    seed = random.randint(0, 100000000)
    image = randomize_image(image, seed, True)
    mask = randomize_image(mask, seed, False)
    return image, mask

def resize(image, mask, input_shape: Tuple[int, int]):
    image = tf.image.resize(image,input_shape)
    mask = tf.image.resize(mask,input_shape)
    return image / 255, mask / 255

def load_images(image, mask):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image)
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image)
    mask = tf.io.read_file(mask)
    mask = tf.io.decode_image(mask, channels=0, expand_animations = False)
    mask = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(mask)
    return image, mask


def get_dataset(image_dir, mask_dir, input_shape: Tuple[int, int], randomize_images=True, batch_size: int = 16, val_split: float = .05) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    images = os.listdir(image_dir)
    masks = [image.replace(".jpg", "_mask.gif") for image in images]
    images = [os.path.join(image_dir,image) for image in images]
    masks = [os.path.join(mask_dir,mask) for mask in masks]
    data = list(zip(images,masks))
    random.shuffle(data)
    
    train_size = math.floor(len(images) * (1-val_split))

    train_data = data[:train_size]
    val_data = data[train_size:]
    train_images, train_masks = zip(*train_data)
    val_images, val_masks = zip(*val_data)

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list(train_images), list(train_masks))).map(map_func=load_images, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list(val_images), list(val_masks))).map(map_func=load_images, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    if randomize_images:
        train_dataset = train_dataset.map(map_func=randomize_images, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(map_func=lambda image, mask: resize(image, mask, input_shape), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).batch(batch_size)
    val_dataset = val_dataset.map(map_func=lambda image, mask: resize(image, mask, input_shape), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).batch(batch_size)


    return train_dataset, val_dataset
```

I'm training it on the service from paperspace.com with a P5000 which has 16 GB memory.
When I go anywhere higher than a batch size of 32, I get the error:

> Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.39GiB with freed_by_count=0

I would expect there to be plenty of space remaining. Can you point me to why I'm running out of memory?

Comment: is it possible you're using a 32-bit version of Python?

Comment: no, it's 64 bit. Maybe it's worth mentioning that i use the service from paperspace.com